# Can't get two inputs from user

Tags: c

I was practicing File I/O. Made a sample program to get personnel data from user and store it in a .txt file as a formatted data, so I can use it for searching inside etc.

Here my code:

```
typedef struct{
    uchar personelNo[20];
    uchar department[40];
    uchar name[20];
    uchar lastname[20];
}Personel;

void add_personnel() {
    FILE* f = fopen(FILE_NAME, "a+");

    Personel temp;

    check("Enter personel name: ", temp.name, 1);
    check("Enter personel surname: ", temp.lastname, 1);
    check("Enter personel department: ", temp.department, 1);

    fprintf(f, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", get_last_p_number(f)+1, temp.name, temp.lastname, temp.department);
}

void error_function(const char* buffer, int no_conversions, char *additional_info) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong. Here: %s , You entered:\n%s\n", additional_info ,buffer);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d successful", no_conversions);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void check(uchar* print_string, uchar* to_be_written, int buffer_size) {
    int r;

    char temps[BUFF_SIZE];

    fprintf(stdout, "%s", print_string);
    //fflush(stdout);

    if (fgets(temps, BUFF_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) error_function(temps, 0, "fgets");
    if ((r = sscanf(temps, " %s", to_be_written)) != buffer_size) error_function(temps, r, "sscanf");
}

int main()
{
    int selection;

    welcome_screen();

    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "Enter your selection: ");

    scanf(" %d", &selection);

    if (selection == 1) {
        add_personnel();
    }
}
```

When I try to run, it works fine, I get my welcome_screen function and when the program asks for my selection. But when i type my selection, it immediately exits with an output like this:

```
Enter personel name: Something went wrong. Here: sscanf , You entered:


-1 successful
```

Yes, I can't even figure out what my error function tells me about. Does anyone knows what the problem is? I thought it was about flushing the buffer, but it got me nowhere when i tried it.

*Edit: Forgot to put add_personel function, now it's here.

Comment: That's not really a [mcve]. It contains functions that are never called, and calls to functions that doesn't exist.

Comment: I also suggest you read more about [the `scanf` function family](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), especially what it *returns*.

Comment: my welcome_screen() function basically contains 1 printf func with
"Welcome, 1 - add 2 - search 3 - chane" nothing else then this.

Comment: OT: A short (and much more efficient) version of `fprintf(stdout, "%s", "Enter your selection: ");` is `fputs("Enter your selection: ", stdout);`

Comment: edited my code and added **add_personel()** now, @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @alk OT:   A good compiler will emit the same efficient code for `fprintf(stdout, "%s", "prompt");` as `fputs("prompt", stdout);` and so not _much more efficient_.  Best to code for clarity - which might be either one, depending on the larger code.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "fopen failed" );`  then cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: this function: `void add_personnel()`  calls `check()` but there is no prototype for `check()` before the call, so the compiler will assume all parameters are of type `int`  Which means the wrong parameters will be passed in the call.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(stdout, "%s", print_string);`  strongly suggest getting in the habit of always ending the format string with `\n` so the data is immediately output to the terminal

Comment: where is the type: `uchar` being defined?

Comment: regarding: `if ((r = sscanf(temps, " %s", to_be_written)) != buffer_size) error_function(temps, r, "sscanf");
}`  That `if()` will 'never' evaluate as TRUE, because all the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers' NOT the length of the extracted char string.

Comment: BTW:  the input format specifiers, except `%c` and `%[...]` consume any leading 'white space'

Comment: OT: regarding the `struct` definition.  Most debuggers will not display the individual fields within the struct unless the struct has a `tag` name

Comment: When calling any of the `scanf()` functions, when using `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

`error_function()` is called when `(r = sscanf(temps, " %s", to_be_written)) != buffer_size` is `false`.  You pass `temps`, `r` and `"sscanf"` to `error_function()`, and the error output indicates that `temps` is an empty string or contains only whitespace, and that `r == -1` which indicates an input failure as expected when `temps` is empty or only whitespace.

The problem occurs due to the earlier `scanf()` call with the `%d` format specifier.  When you type:

```
1<newline>
```

the `%d` consumes only the `1` digit, leaving the `<newline>` buffered and later extracted by the subsequent `fgets()` call.

To ensure you consume (and discard) any non-digit characters following the `selection` entry - read all characters until the `<newline>`:

```
scanf( "%d", &selection ) ;
int discard = 0;
do{ discard == getchar() ; } while( discard != '\n' && discard != EOF ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the perspective, didn't realise the newline character was being put there until i used a whitespace before the formatter %s in `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by changing my check function from this:

```
void check(uchar* print_string, uchar* to_be_written, int buffer_size) {
    int r;

    char temps[BUFF_SIZE];

    fprintf(stdout, "%s", print_string);
    //fflush(stdout);

    if (fgets(temps, BUFF_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) error_function(temps, 0, "fgets");
    if ((r = sscanf(temps, " %s", to_be_written)) != buffer_size) error_function(temps, r, "sscanf");
}
```

To this:

```
void check(uchar* print_string, uchar* to_be_written, int buffer_size) {
    int r;

    fprintf(stdout, "%s", print_string);
    //fflush(stdout);

    if ((r = fscanf(stdin, " %s", to_be_written)) != buffer_size) error_function(stdin, r, "sscanf");
}
```

And it worked.
Thanks to @user3121023 for pointing out not to mix `fgets` and `scanf`.

Comment: `fscanf( stdin ...` is equivalent to just `scanf(...`.  This solution works but is not robust. If a user types `1@<newline>`- which may happen if they mis-key an entry, it will still fail, or rather `@` will be accepted as the name.  Mixing `fgets()` and `sscanf()` was not really the issue - knowing why mixing them can cause problems is the key to solid code, not blindly following some "rule of thumb".  You have simply switched one set of potential problems for a different set.

Comment: The `' '` in `fscanf(stdin, " %s",...` serves no purpose.   Same as `"%s"`.

Comment: Mixing `fgets` and `scanf` is good insight.  Using `scanf()` instead of `fgets()` is not the wise choice.  This code does not prevent buffer overflow.